# Link CSS from another folder?

Tags: html, css

I am making a website and I am trying to find a way to link my CSS file that is in other folder but I have no idea how to do it. At this moment I got it in the same folder as the HTML code. Also is it the same to link JS as the CSS because I need to link that to.

Comment: So which part of the linking are you having trouble with?

Comment: http://www.iusmentis.com/technology/www/relativeurls/

Comment: provide your folder structure to give specific details

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your current folder is `/current/folder/location/index.html`, and your `.css` file is in `/current/second/folder/style.css`, then use this as an example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../second/folder/style.css">
```

or alternatively:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/current/second/folder/style.css">
```

However, if the second file is in `/current/folder/second/style.css, then use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../second/style.css">
```

Answer (score 4):

You can navigate within your folder structure with using a relative path in your html `<link>` tag

for example

```
<link href="../css/main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

will go one folder up (../) and then select the main.css in the css folder

Answer (score 1):

for linking to a css file from a html file, the `<link>` tag is used with

1. a `type` of `text/css`
2. a `rel` value of `stylesheet`
3. and `href` which is the address of your css file.

   ```
   <link href="ADDRESS_OF_CSS_FILE" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
   ```

**ADDRESS_OF_CSS_FILE** is either:

- an **absolute path** (the complete path of the file on your computer,
  including the **C:** driver for instance)

  `<link href="C://unneccessary/toType/folders/myProjectFolder/myStylesFolder" rel=...>`
- or a **relative path** (the path relative to the html file that you are
  putting your `<link>` tag into it.)

  assuming this is your directory structure

  ```
  /Desktop
    /myProjectFolder
      index.html
      /myStylesFolder
        my_styles.css
  ```

  you are putting the `<link>` tag inside of `index.html`, and `index.html` is inside `/myProjectFolder`, so the **current Folder** for the `link` tag is `myProjectFolder`.

  you have to tell the browser:

  - from the **current directory**
  - go to the `/StylesFolder` which is in the **current directory**
  - and from there, load `my_styles.css` file

    and you tell the browser to do that like this:

    ```
    href="./myStylesFolder/my_styles.css"
    ```

    the browser understands `./` as the **current directory**, and `../` as the parent of the current directory, in this case: `/Desktop`

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your index.html into head targets

```css
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="myfile.css"/>
</head>
```

When you have the file in other folder you must use `../myfile.css` or `../../myfile.css`. The `../` is referenced to the parent folder

Answer (score 0):

No need to add a path like this: `E:\Naruto\css files\new.css`.
Instead, add a path like this `\css files\new.css` in the `<link>`.
Also, my HTML file is stored in `E:\Naruto\html files\New.html`

[image]

Comment: It is better if you copy and paste the code into the answer instead of sharing a screenshot of it. If you do it will make it easier for the asker to implement your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have a "Project" name folder.
Inside that you have "html", "CSS" and "Script" name folders.
You want to connect the "style.css" from CSS folder to "index.html" of html folder, for that type:

in the above tag, the attribute showing:
first forward slash '/': to look into previous folder.
CSS: folder name.
Second forward slash '/': to look into CSS folder.
style.css: file name.

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style/Style.css" type="text/css">
```

/**Folder's name**/file.css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hkKQ.png)

Enjoy!!