# Linking an external CSS from another folder does not work?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, external

I have problem linking a CSS file from another folder (project structure & link tag in the picture below). I have read many SO questions about this but nothing can make my linking work. Am I blind or is there something I missed?

[image]

Edit: Add files content:

**index.html**

```
...
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/assets/css/style.css" />
    <!-- this works fine
    <style>
      body {
        background: rgb(100,0,255);
        background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(100,0,255,1) 0%, rgba(100,0,255,1) 30%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
        background-attachment: fixed
          }
    </style>-->
  </head>
...
```

**style.css**

```
body {
    background: rgb(100,0,255);
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(100,0,255,1) 0%, rgba(100,0,255,1) 30%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
    background-attachment: fixed
}
```

Comment: The path to your .css looks fine -- are you definitely applying a style within your .css to a matching tag/class/id in your .html? Perhaps share the contents of both those files with us?

Comment: @Johannes That I also tried, still not working. BTW: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34110819/link-css-from-another-folder

Comment: @Marco I just added a background-color to the <body> tag. That works well when the style is included in a <style> tag, but not with the link...

Comment: Interesting.. what happens if you move your index.html file up one level (outside of /public) and reference your stylesheet href as '/src/assets/css/style.css'? Does that work?

Comment: Also, as local file structures are a little hard to get assistance on, could you try replicating the basic structure in an online IDE? E.g. hit 'Fork Template' on this and share the output once you've recreated a file structure and your .html is able to run: https://replit.com/@replit/HTML-CSS-JS?v=1#index.html

Comment: Ok so apparently it is because my project is actually a React project so the CSS had to be imported in ```App.js```. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: No problem, and well done on solving it! Might be worth writing an answer to this question with that explanation, and marking it as solved to help anyone else with a similar problem in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Because your project is actually a React project, so you have to import CSS file in App.js.

For example, assuming that your global.css is located in /styles directory,
you have to import it in App.js.

./styles/global.css

```
body {
    background: rgb(100,0,255);
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(100,0,255,1) 0%, rgba(100,0,255,1) 30%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
    background-attachment: fixed
}
```

./App.js

```
import './styles/globals.css';

function App(props) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok so apparently it is because my project is actually a React project so the CSS had to be imported in `App.js`